# @EJB injection not work switching from Sun JAXWS to Metro 2.3 @Webservice with Oracle Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: dependency-injection, weblogic, jax-ws, ejb-3.0

I'm developing a web-service with `EJB 3.0 And Spring 3.2,on Weblogic 10.3.5` application Server.

At first,using the **default Weblogic JAXWS implementation**,

I am able to inject an ejb instance into the @Webservice class with @EJB annotation.

Then I moved from default weblogic JAXWS implementation to METRO STACK (Jaxws 2.3). All seems to work well execpet for EJB dependency injection. Now fooEJB instance is always null.

```
@Webservice
public class HelloService
{
    @EJB
    private IFooEJB fooEJB; // Work only with default weblogic JAXWS implementation

}
```

**Is there a way to make @EJB di working with METRO JAXWS 2.3 ?**

Thank you

Comment: For me, this didn't work on WebLogic 12c and I had to do a JNDI lookup to get the EJB. Maybe this is related to JAX-WS being a newer version.